# Relative clause or Purpose clause?

Tags: clauses

1. *Only sentence (3) is precise in its meaning, and the other two would need context **to make them clear**.*

Does it mean:

a) ...need context **in order** to make them clear.

Or

b) ...need context **that could** make them clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A " ...need context in order to make them clear." would seem to be the obvious meaning.